# Should I use lasso with alpha set to (0 for Python; 1 for R) to avoid prohibitively long svd calculations when doing OLS?

Tags: regression, lasso, linear, computational-statistics

When I use Lasso from `sklearn.linear_model` the computation times are in the vicinity of 5 - 10 seconds using alpha = 0, which is equivalent to OLS. However, if I try and use the function `LinearRegression` from the same package, it takes over 20 minutes!

Here is the code (will provide more context if interested):

These are the packages that may be needed (redundancy is likely):

```py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.image import imread
    import scipy.fftpack as spfft
    from   scipy.fft import fft, dct
     
    from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    
    from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
    from skimage import io
    from PIL import Image
```

The code is trying (successfully) to reproduce [this simulation of compressed SENSE](http://www.pyrunner.com/weblog/2016/05/26/compressed-sensing-python/), but this is irrelevant to the post. The general idea is that the values of the pixels of a black and white image are the regressand ("dependent variable") in a lasso regression. The regressors are cosine values - the basis vectors in a discrete cosine transform.

```py
    # Loading an image that will be used as the regressand:
    urls = ['https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9312897/117540238-3e6e1600-afdc-11eb-98ec-727b8629e2a7.png']  
    
    for url in urls:
      image = io.imread(url) 
    
    # This part is not related to the actual question (prepares the regressors
    #... and the model matrix.
    X = np.mean(image,-1);
    ny, nx = X.shape
    k  = round(nx * ny * 0.8) # % sample
    ri = np.random.choice(nx * ny, k, replace=False)
    b  = X.T.flat[ri] # These are the actual pixels chosen.
    b  = np.expand_dims(b, axis=1)
    A  = np.kron( # outer product
       spfft.idct(np.eye(nx), norm='ortho', axis=0), 
       spfft.idct(np.eye(ny), norm='ortho', axis=0)  
        )
    A  = A[ri,:]
```

First the lasso regression, which takes a minimal amount of time, even using an alpha value of 0, which is supposed to be the equivalent of an OLS according to [Python documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html):

> `alpha`: float, default=1.0
> Constant that multiplies the L1 term. Defaults to 1.0. alpha = 0 is equivalent to an ordinary least square, solved by the LinearRegression object. For numerical reasons, using alpha = 0 with the Lasso object is not advised. Given this, you should use the LinearRegression object.

```py
    # Here is the lasso regression (fast, even with an alpha = 0 (~ OLS).
    lasso = Lasso(alpha=0)
    lasso.fit(A, b)
```

The last chunk is the actual OLS with the `LinearRegression` formula in the same `sklearn` package. If you run it, be ready to wait for over 20 minutes...

```py
    # The OLS is commented out because it will freeze the computer for 20 min.
    # coefs = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(A, b).coef_
```

Lasso uses coordinate descend, whereas `LinearRegression` calculates a huge SVD. I tested the SVD independent of the rest of the inversion, and it is indeed extremely long.

---

Echoing the comments, I tried with [`statsmodels` and specifying `QR` method](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.GLS.fit.html), and the computation was ongoing after 10 minutes, at which point I stopped it:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.OLS(b, A)
results = model.fit(method='qr')
print(results.summary())
```

---

To illustrate the idea of using the lasso function in lieu of OLS, I can resort to R and `mtcars`, where I can run a back-of-the-envelope example, and get the same coefficients as for `lm`:

Using the library `glmnet` and keeping in mind the [glmnet documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf):

> The elasticnet mixing parameter, with $0 ≤ α ≤ 1.$ The penalty is defined as
> $$(1 − α)/2||β||_2^2 + α||β||1.$$
> alpha=1 is the lasso penalty, and alpha=0 the ridge penalty.

```r
    > library(glmnet)
    > # Regressing miles per gallon over other technical car specs:
    > x <- data.matrix(mtcars[, c("hp", "wt", "drat")])
    > y <- mtcars[, "mpg"]
    > lambda <- 0 
    > fit <- glmnet(x_var, mtcars$mpg, alpha=1, lambda=0)
    > coef(fit) The following are the coefficients with lasso (coord. descend)
    4 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                         s0
    (Intercept) 29.39776427
    hp          -0.03221865
    wt          -3.22883782
    drat         1.61457281
    > # Specifying the lm() OLS yields the same coefficients:
    > lm(y_var ~ x_var)
    
    Call:
    lm(formula = y_var ~ x_var)
    
    Coefficients:
    (Intercept)      x_varhp      x_varwt    x_vardrat  
       29.39493     -0.03223     -3.22795      1.61505
```

Comment: Third option, perhaps (much) better than either: find a library that uses QR decomposition.

Comment: @whuber Makes sense. That is what `lm()` already does. This seems like an example of R > Python for stats.

Comment: Python's `statsmodels` might have a better OLS implementation than `sklearn`. @Mathtourist

Comment: @Dave I tried with `statsmodels` and specifying `QR` to no avail.

Comment: what's the dimensionality of your problem and what do you want to do with those results afterward? If you want to also do some statistical tests, look at SEs or CIs, then sklearn won't help you with that

Comment: If I interpret your setup code correctly, then you have a very large design matrix with more columns than rows, more variables than observations. OLS is not intended for that case.

Comment: @Josef No, the model matrix is square `(16284, 16284)`. And I have the same time problem running the SVD.

Comment: But your `k < nx * ny`. 16K variables is large for linear algebra using dense matrices. Also, valid inference in OLS assumes that number of observations is considerably larger than the number of parameters.